# submit button not returning value via AJAX/JQuery to self-processing form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form which opens in Colorbox and is submitted via Ajax/JQuery to itself. However, it seems as if the data passed is not including the value of the submit button itself. Whether I use multiple submits or just one, there is no data in $_POST['submitButton'], and it doesn't respond to isset() or empty().

The rest of the form posts just fine though. I can echo $_POST['name'] and $_POST['email'], just not $_POST['submitButton']

Here is (a stripped down version of) my form:

```
<form id="sub-process" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input name="name" type="text" value="">
<input name="email" type="text" value="">
<input name="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And here is the jquery that processes the form to be submitted via AJAX, rather than an HTTP request.

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('.cbox-form').colorbox({maxWidth: '75%', onComplete: function(){
cbox_submit();
}});
});

function cbox_submit()
{
jQuery("#sub-process").submit(function(){
jQuery.post(
  jQuery(this).attr('action'),
  jQuery(this).serialize(),
  function(data){
    jQuery().colorbox({html: data, onComplete: function(){
      cbox_submit();
    }});
  }
);
return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: `serialize` won't include submit button value because form was not submited by submit button. Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string.

Comment: Thats frustrating. I'm considering working around it with a hidden value, but what JS would I use to change the value of that hidden button depending on which button is clicked and submit the form?

Comment: Put a click handler on the submit button, and have it add an appropriate property to the object that it submits.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to change my extra buttons to checkboxes, and let "checked" trigger the required actions, that way I can maintain one submit, and use a hidden value to check isset($_POST['submit'])

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but It looks like people do not understand that @itachi has the correct answer.

The serialize method will NEVER return a value from the submit button. It does not return the submit button in the post.
You will do best to just use a hidden form field and adding a click event to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$_POST['submitButton']`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the OP stated there is no data in $_POST['submitButton']

Comment: I just edited when i realized that i had written $_POST['submit'] at first, instead of $_POST['submitButton']. I've tried both, to no avail.

Comment: try var_dump($_POST) to view all values stored in $_POST array

Comment: Update: Same issue when I use JS to submit the form - onClick="document.forms["sub-process"].submit();"

Comment: var_dump($_POST) yields: array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "test" ["email"]=> string(13) "test@test.com" }

Comment: I suppose I could insert <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="submit"> and check that for isset, but that eliminates multiple buttons support, unless I change that value to "add" or "remove" with js depending on the button clicked... Seems so roundabout.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's serialize() function is kind of quirky and particular. I find it to be not so useful for many scenarios. You may want to try the [serializeObject](http://danheberden.com/jquery-plugin-serializeobject-2011-04-01/) plugin. I've found it to work in many cases when serialize() does not work for me.

Comment: it is peculiar about it because that's the w3 standard in the definition of successful controls.