# how to differentiate between 2 input tags in a form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having an issue with 2 input tags in a form.
What i want to achieve is that when one certain input is choosen, an echo must be generated.

My form:

```
<form method="post" id="quickpoll">
......
<input class="quickpollsubmit" type="submit" name="quickpollsubmit" value="View">
<input class="quickpollsubmit" type="submit" name="quickpollsubmit" value="Vote">
```

The js:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#quickpoll', function()
{
var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({

    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'quickpoll_vote.php',
    data : data,
    success :  function(data)
               {                        
                    $("#quickpoll").fadeOut(500).hide(function()
                    {
                        $(".quickpollwrapper").fadeIn(500).show(function()
                        {
                            $(".quickpollwrapper").html(data);

                        });


                    });

               }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**quickpoll_vote.php:**

```
if($_POST)
{
   if($_POST['quickpollsubmit'] == 'View') {
   echo 'you choose View';
   }
}
```

The echo does not appear at all, whether i choose View input or Vote input.
The echo should only appear when i choose View input
What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Try if(!empty($_POST)) instead of if($_POST) considering post is always an array.

Comment: @Nitin unfortunately; that does make no difference

Comment: @Nitin an empty array is a "falsey" value (loosly casts to a false value in a comparison expression).

Comment: Check this link it talks about similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form

Comment: use only  `$(".quickpollwrapper").html(data);` inside `success`: just to see if data comes from server

Comment: Hold up... You serialize form data but the submit button should be added manually if i am not mistaken. Try this $(document).on('click', '.quickpollsubmit', function(){ var data = { quickpollsubmit:$(this).val() }; ...

Comment: You are right nitin. But your method would exclude any other input in the form (force data to one element). I added a working sample to my previous answer.

Comment: In that case, serialize the data using $(this).closest('form').serialize(); and combine the submit button value with the rest of the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[citation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424034/submit-button-not-returning-value-via-ajax-jquery-to-self-processing-form?rq=1) of stephen nielsen :

"The serialize method will NEVER return a value from the submit button. It does not return the submit button in the post. You will do best to just use a hidden form field and adding a click event to the button"

To check this point, add a :

```
print_r($_POST);
```

in the begin of quickpoll_vote.php

You will see that the argument "quickpollsubmit" has no value, whatever button you click.

Here's a way of solving this.

```js
 $(document).on('click', '.quickpollsubmit', function()
    {
    $('#quickpollsubmit').val($(this).val());
    var data = $("#quickpoll").serialize();
       
        $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'quickpoll_vote.php',
        data : data,
        success :  function(data)
                   {                        
                        $("#quickpoll").fadeOut(500).hide(function()
                        {
                            $(".quickpollwrapper").fadeIn(500).show(function()
                            {
                                $(".quickpollwrapper").html(data);
    
                            });
    
    
                        });
    
                   }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" name="quickpollsubmit" id="quickpollsubmit" readonly>
<input class="quickpollsubmit" type="submit" value="View">
<input class="quickpollsubmit" type="submit" value="Vote">
```

I edited the code so it will be compatible with your PHP part, but this way some element are really bad named, sorry about this.

In your script, use a hidden input instead of the text one, here for demonstration.

Comment: I confirm; this works great! I will create a hidden field like you said. Thanks @technico for this solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to see if a button was selected in PHP. However, in this case you have two HTML form elements with the same name, so those need to be unique as shown below.

```
<form method="post" id="quickpoll">
......
<input class="quickpollsubmit" type="submit" name="quickpollView" value="View">
<input class="quickpollsubmit" type="submit" name="quickpollVote" value="Vote">


if($_POST)
{
   if(isset($_POST['quickpollView']) {
       echo 'you choose View';
   } else if(isset($_POST['quickpollVote']) {
       echo 'you choose Vote';
   }
}
```

Comment: i tried this but without result...I got no echo at all

Comment: Check this link it talks about similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
if ($_POST['quickpollsubmit'] == 'View') {
    //action for view
} else if ($_POST['quickpollsubmit'] == 'Vote') {
    //action for vore
} else {
    //invalid action!
}
```

Comment: Not related to the real issue : OP's original `if ($_POST['quickpollsubmit'] == 'View') {...}` is enough to generate the problem. As the real issue is that no values are send, there's no chance that any change on the reception part could help. Or maybe `print_r($_POST)` ?